# R Studio not using the newest R version on my computer

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, updates

I installed R 3.5.3, then restarted my Windows 7 computer. Next I launched R Studio and ran the command `sessionInfo()` and am informed that R Studio is still utilizing R version 3.5.1.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

I went to the `Tools > Global Options > General > R Version` and get a screen like this

[image: r version windows]
<sub>(source: [rstudio.com](https://www.rstudio.com/images/docs/versions_windows.png))</sub>

Although I could simply select the specific version of R I'd like to use (eg 3.5.3) I want R Studio to use the default version of R on my machine, which I'd always want to be the most current version of R on my machine.

How do I achieve this? I'm using the [installr](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/) package to update R every six months or so. It seems [installr](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/) doesn't force Windows 7 to realize I've got a new R version on my system.

Comment: Maybe delete the old version? Or set the newer(st) as the default?

Comment: @NelsonGon How do set a default version of R system wide on Windows 7? Also can't delete the older versions (easily) because our IT rules allow installing, but not deleting.

Comment: Click `Browse` above. Browse to wherever the R version is or try changing defaults by file type although I think .R files open with RStudio and not R.

Comment: @JasonHunter: fyi there aren't many changes between `3.5.1` and `3.5.3`. [`3.6.0` will be released in about 2 weeks with a lot more fixes and new features](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html)

Comment: So does `installr` not use the standard Windows installer? Because I believe the Windows installer sets a registry key to let the system know what the latest version of R is (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\Current Version`, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-use-the-Registry_003f)). If installr does something else, it might skip that step. Maybe file an issue with them.

Comment: @MrFlick It can only do so if the user has admin rights.

Comment: And I do not have admin rights on this Win7 work machine. Perhaps this is the root cause. I can try on my personal Windows machine at home and verify, unless somebody else can before I make it home.